# Multiple actions for checkbox list

Tags: php, html, forms, user-interface, checkbox

I have a list of multiple items with having a checkbox for each row (like gmail list of emails).

User selects checkboxes and then press an action button to perform some action on selected items ( delete for example). Then the list of selected items will be sent to php file for background processing.

But what is the solution for performing multiple actions on selected checkboxes ( For instance, in gmail, we do delete, mark as spam, mark as read/unread etc..).

Here is what I have:

[image: design]

Comment: give your sample query.

Comment: Current query has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different "submit buttons" for each actions. Give same name but different values. Then check it to backend

For example,

**HTML**

```
<form action="backend.php" method="post" >
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Move" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Copy" />

    <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="value 1" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="value 2" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="value 3" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="value 4" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="value 5" >
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
..................
..................

if($_POST['action'] == "Delete")
    .......
else if($_POST['action'] == "Move")
    .......
else if($_POST['action'] == "Copy")
    .......
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give the checkboxes a name that would result in a php item array after a post the form. 
For example, `name="item[]"`

When the form is posted you can then loop through the items in the array with,

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $item) {
    /* do action */
}
```

Comment: I asked about different actions. Not a single action on selected list.

Comment: My answer is about how to handle the multiple items one by one in a loop. The action taken should be sent along when the form is posted.

So youve got the item[] checkboxes + an additional action field (with multiple options ie dropdown etc) in your html form.

Comment: I got you. But what would if we want "checkboxes + button (not any dropdown)"